# firefox absolute positioning working differently than all browser

Tags: css, firefox

I've tested in all browsers chrome, IE, Opera, Safari and it's working fine but just not in latest version of firefox.

[image]

```css
body{
    background: red;
    margin: 120px 0;
}

#caption {
    font-size: 36px;
    position: relative;
}
.captions {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.border-top {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    width: 100%;
}
.captions > span {
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
.linebreak {
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 0;
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="captions">
 <span id="caption">
         <span class="border-top">&nbsp;</span>
         <span id="caption-title">Foo Bar</span>
    </span>
    <span class="linebreak">&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="slogan-title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</span>
</div>
```

As you can see the line is going beyond the div `Foo Bar`. How can I fix this (if possible without changing the markup) ?

Comment: Your code looks strange to me, why don't you use margin-bottom:12px instead of absolute positioning + top:-12px; ? Everything could be greatly simplified, and maybe you will have less rendering problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `#caption` to `display:inline-block`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Lkb4ncgb/

```css
body{
    background: red;
    margin: 120px 0;
}

#caption {
    font-size: 36px;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.captions {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.border-top {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    width: 100%;
}
.captions > span {
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
.linebreak {
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 0;
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="captions">
 <span id="caption">
         <span class="border-top">&nbsp;</span>
         <span id="caption-title">Foo Bar</span>
    </span>
    <span class="linebreak">&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="slogan-title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't noticed that span!

Comment: i have used display:inline-block so that it adjust to the children width or i can also use display:block